# TTimePicker adds a 1899/12/30 date when changed

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, formatdatetime, tdatetime

I am busy writing a program in Delphi 11.3 that works with times. Specifically, a start and end time, and it's calculating the time spent between the two, as well as if the one is bigger than the other.

Things are going haywire despite using `MinutesBetween()` or `MinuteSpan()`. My start time may be `08:00` and my end time `09:30`. If I use `if start < end`, I'll get False yet it is True. Calculating the time spent equates to over 100 years. Odd stuff like this.

As a test, I wrote a small program with the following code:

```
mmo1.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss.zzz',tmpckr1.Time)+'   '
+FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss.zzz',tmpckr2.Time)+'   '
+IntToStr(MinutesBetween(tmpckr1.Time,tmpckr2.Time))+'   '
+FloatToStr(MinuteSpan(tmpckr1.Time,tmpckr2.Time)));
```

This is running in a `TTimer`. The output is as expected:

```
2023/09/18 20:46:29.571   2023/09/18 20:46:29.571   0   0
```

I'll click on `tmpckr1` and then OK tick at the bottom. Note I don't change anything on the time and this is the result.

```
1899/12/30 20:46:29.571   2023/09/18 20:46:29.571   65069280   65069280
```

I repeat and this time with `tmpckr2`:

```
2023/09/18 20:46:29.571   1899/12/30 20:46:29.571   65069280   65069280
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or will I have to do some magic using `EncodeDate()`, `EncodeTime()`, `ReplaceDate()` and `ReplaceTime()` so that the `TTime` value of the `TTimePicker`s actually match, or am I over-complicating things?

If I'm just dealing with `TTime`, why is the date even a factor? Why is the date changing in the `TTimePicker` once it has an `OnChange` event?

Answer (score 5):

You are asking `FormatDateTime()` to output a date for a `TTime` value that does not have a date component defined.

`TDate`, `TTime`, and `TDateTime` are all just aliases for `Double`, where the "date component" represents `1899-12-30` when the integral portion of the `Double` is `0`.

`TTimePicker.Time` is *supposed* to return a `TTime` value with only a time component present, not a date component.  So, the fact that your output includes a non-zero date at all is clearly a bug, but that doesn't matter because you should be ignoring the date to begin with since it has no defined meaning in this situation.

You need to fix your code to ignore the date when formatting the `TTimePicket.Time` value.  I also find it best to use the RTL's [`DateOf()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.DateOf) and [`TimeOf()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.TimeOf) functions when dealing with `TDate`/`TTime`/`TDateTime` values containing undefined components, especially values returned by UI controls like `TDateTimePicker`, `TMonthCalendar`, `TTimePicker`, etc for exactly this kind of situation.

Try this:

```
FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz', TimeOf(tmpckr1.Time))
FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz', TimeOf(tmpckr2.Time))

// just to demonstrate that a zero date is being returned properly...
FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', TimeOf(tmpckr1.Time))
FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', TimeOf(tmpckr2.Time))

MinutesBetween(TimeOf(tmpckr1.Time), TimeOf(tmpckr2.Time)))
MinuteSpan(TimeOf(tmpckr1.Time), TimeOf(tmpckr2.Time)))
```

```
start := TimeOf(tmpckr1.Time);
end := TimeOf(tmpckr2.Time);
if start < end then ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand the TTimePicker.Time value is supposed to be a TTime value - and it even shows as such in Delphi. I just could not figure out why the results I was getting weren't as expected, like when using an if-statement or a MinuteSpan. Initially I did only output the time using TimeToStr and that was fine. In the end I usedthe FormatDateTime to just try and see what exactly was going on and that's where I saw that clicking on the TTimePicker changed the date value. TimeOf is the perfect solution and I am now getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Well. TDateTime is a double data type, Where **int** part is for store date and **fractional** part for time. So 1232.25 implies 1232 for date (1232 days from 1899/12/30) and 0.25 (a quarter of day, 24/4 ergo 6 am). Good for date-time arithmetic.

If you want to ignore the Date Part, change

```
MinutesBetween(tmpckr1.Time,tmpckr2.Time)
```

for

```
MinutesBetween(frac(tmpckr1.Time),frac(tmpckr2.Time))
```

If you want to ignore the time Part, change

```
MinutesBetween(trunc(tmpckr1.Time),trunc(tmpckr2.Time))
```

now, why is tmpckr2 returning TDateTime or Time, i'm not sure.

Comment: I find `DateOf()` and `TimeOf()` to be more readable than `Trunc()` and `Frac()`, respectively, when dealing with date/time values.